# UNIX command: faster than diff

Tags: performance, unix, command, diff

For a long time I've been making backups on two external drives. And these drives are driving me crazy.

Although the general information stored on 2 drives is the same, their filesize is different, because of the hidden files (like .DS_Store). So far I've been using the root directory size to be sure that those two backups are same. If both roots indicate the same size in bytes, I could be pretty sure they are same. But hidden files are really a pain in the neck.

I tried to use diff, this way:

```
diff -rq -x '.*' dir1 dir2
```

But this is **incredibly slow**. I beg you, guys, help me finding a way to check if two huge directories contain same data.

My idea is to make some recursive command that would be comparing only filenames + filesizes. That should be much faster than diff, which is actually comparing each file.

PS: The backup has over 700 GB.

Comment: What do you guys think about `diff <(cd dir1 && du -a [!.]* | sort -k2) <(cd dir2 && du -a [!.]* | sort -k2)?` Just wrote it, but I'm not quite sure it's 100% right, although it passed some simple tests.

Comment: `diff` may be a bit much for what you're doing. If two files are different, it's going to try to figure out why. My unix is a little rusty, but isn't there a command for comparing files, like `fcmp` or something? If not, it should be pretty simple to write one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsync` to show you what is different with something along these lines:

```
rsync -aHv --delete --dry-run dir1/ dir2/
```

It's not necessarily the most useful output format if you want to process it with other utilities, but for human review, it's ok...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider calculating a checksum on both drives and compare the output. 
this should be much faster than diff, although it will take some time to run.

Try:

```
$ find -s somedir -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | md5sum
```

You can see in the find command that hidden files are ignored.

You may also think of a way to calculate directory size without hidden files.

Referenced from:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/how-do-i-get-the-md5-sum-of-a-directorys-contents-as-one-sum